# Serious trouble inserting image in MacTex

Tags: graphics, external-files, paths

So I was using the online editor Writelatex and inserting images there is pretty straightforward. However, it's quite slow so I began to use MacTex.

I'm using the `\usepackage{graphicx}` but I guess the nucleus of my problem is that I don't know how to create the folderpath on mac. My two images are on my desktop. Here is what I've tried:

```
\graphicspath{{/Users/david villarreal/Desktop}}
```

and when I have to insert the two images I say

```
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{B.png}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{A.png}
```

Can somebody tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

When I ask the program to tell me what error I have it highlights the following:

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a / after Desktop

Comment: You don't actually mention what the problem is or which error and warning messages (if any) you get. Please consider posting a full [MWE](I've just been asked to write a minimal example. What's that?) rather than just some code snippets.

Comment: I've added the exact section MacTex highlights for me when there's an error.

Comment: Problem solved. I have to eliminate the space between my user name. thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also note that the red squiggly lines aren't LaTeX errors—your editor thinks that they're spelling mistakes `:)`